# ruby parse date using strptime and strftime

Tags: ruby

So I'm parsing this string from AIX's errpt - to convert it into epoch - and it doesn't seem to be respecting the Hour and Minute part of the string.

So the string is: 1108095913 (MMDDHHMMYY) .. but when I do my strptime to convert it to a date object, and then format it how I want, it completely zero'd out my hour and minute.

Am I missing something?

```
irb(main):039:0> Date.strptime("1108095913", "%m%d%H%M%y").strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

=> "11/08/13 00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Time.strptime instead of Date method, Date removes hours and minutes

```
1.9.3-p429 :005 > Time.strptime("1108095913", "%m%d%H%M%y").strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
 => "11/08/13 09:59"
```

Comment: I'm on 1.8.7 - is that a 1.9 feature?
irb(main):001:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Time.strptime("1108095913", "%m%d%H%M%y").strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
NoMethodError: undefined method `strptime' for Time:Class
        from (irb):2
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:194
irb(main):003:0>

Comment: @awojo yeah i use 1.9.3, i can't try it right now on 1.8.7 but it looks like its aliased in 1.9.3, try DateTime as mentioned above. `require 'time'`, and `DateTime.strptime("1108095913", "%m%d%H%M%y").strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) instead of `Date`:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> DateTime.strptime("1108095913", "%m%d%H%M%y").strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
=> "11/08/13 09:59"
```

The reason is `DateTime` handles date and time, both and `Date` only handles date.

Hope this helps!